# Can I make a color background take up only a % of an element without making an image?

Tags: css

If I want to have a blue bar in the background at the top of my webpage (so the body element's background), but I want it to be 100px in height and span the entire horizontal background... is there any way to do this without making a background image that is 100px with the color I want (and maybe 1px in width) and making it repeat-x?

Basically, rather than doing:

```
background: url("images/pagestripe.png") repeat-x;
```

I want to do this:

```
background: #FFCCFF 100px top left repeat-x;
```

Which would give me a 100px background of the color #FFCCFF that starts in the top left of the page and repeats horizontally.

Similarly, if I wanted it to repeat-y, it would make the 100px the width instead of the height.

The positioning markers can represent offsets...

Is this possible? Is there actual CSS code for what I am looking for? Perhaps I'm not far off...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient):

```
body {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue 100px, transparent 0);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, blue 100px, transparent 0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, blue 100px, transparent 0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, blue 100px, transparent 0);
}
```

Edit: This is CSS3 only. For CSS2 you may try

```
body:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the bar a separate `div` and set a negative margin on it.  Something like this:

```
<div id="bluebar"></div>
Content goes here...
```

And then in CSS:

```
div#bluebar {
    background: #fcf;  /* that's actually pink, but whatever... */
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

I'd give a jsFiddle link, but they're apparently down for maintenance right now, so [here's a simple static HTML demo](http://vyznev.net/misc/pinkbar.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

You can create a single full width element with the height and background color you desire.

Use CSS to position the element.

```
div#bluebar {
    background: #acf;
    display: block;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; /* however far from the top you would like it*/
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10; /* or some other number that will place it below the appropriate elements */
}
```

Just be sure that the parent of #blubar does not have `position:relative;` set or it will position relative to the parent not the document.